# How to change the root path of signed in user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

How to make the root path change when the user is logged in? *(I'm using devise)*

In application controller I have:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    '/dashboard' || user_dashboard_path
  end
```

in routes.rb I've tried:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: "subscribers#new"

  authenticated :user do
    get '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index', as: :dashboard
    root to: "dashboard#index", as: :user_dashboard
  end
```

But what's happening is, upon signing up it's re_directing to /dashboard which is great, however if I click the home link which links to root path it goes back to subscribers#new, when it should be going to dashboard#index because the user is signed in.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this in your routes file:

```
authenticated :user do
  root to: "home#index"
end

unauthenticated :user do
  root "home#visitor"
end
```

Docs here:  http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:authenticated